# Why does length not appear as a key in an array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So just a question about how the array works in java script, Here's some behavior;

```
var a = [1,2,3,4]
Object.keys(a)
>> ['0','1','2','3']
a['0']
>> 1
a.length
>> 4
a.something = 'value'
a
>> [1,2,3,4]
console.log(a)
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, something: "value"]
Object.keys(a)
>> ['0','1','2','3','something']
a.something
>> 'value'
a.length
>> 4
a.length = 5
a 
>>[1, 2, 3, 4, undefined]
console.log(a)
>>[1, 2, 3, 4, something: "value"]
Object.keys(a)
>> ["0", "1", "2", "3", "something"]
a.length = 'len'
> Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length(…)
```

My question is, why does 'length' not show up as a key in the array object? It pretty much acts like on, although It seems to get parsed to an int. If it's not a function or a key, what is it?

Comment: It'll show up if you use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`, which gets all non-inherited properties, irrespective of their enumerable setting.

Comment: Thanks! this has been bothering me for a really long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`length` is an object propery with the [**property descriptor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor), `enumerable`, set as `false`. Thus, it will not show when you iterate over its *keys*

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( a, 'length' ));

// => ... enumerable: false ...
```

I recommend this [**text**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md#property-descriptors) which is related to the question

Comment: @lonewarrior556, no problem, I love it and am reading it myself :-)